# why the result is correct without __syncthreads()?

Tags: cuda

The CUDA kernel function is used to calculate inner product for two vectors. The kernel used multiple threads to calculate products concurrently, and then uses one thread to calculate inner product.
My question is why the result would be correct without __syncthreads().

```
__global__ void dot( int *a, int *b, int *c, int *dot ){
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int i;

    c[tid] = a[tid] * b[tid];
    
    //__syncthreads();
    //need synchronize?? 
    if(tid==0){
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            *dot += c[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the block size?

Comment: Probably because you were lucky. This not not guaranteed to work without synchronization.

Comment: You could test by putting a `if(tid > 0)__nanosleep(1000000);` in the beginning to sleep 1ms for all except thread 0. You can find out the order of threads by atomically increasing a counter and storing the current value in a separate memory location depending on thread number. The increasing counter number is the order the threads executed this source code location.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, thread #0 is accessing every elements in array c (results by other threads). So the result would be wrong unless you secure that every calculation on array c is completed by using __syncthreads();.

Comment: If you get correct result consistently, I think it's because your if + for loop can be so slow that every thread can complete 2 reads + 1 multiply + 1 write operation.

Comment: It could also be that only one warp is active and the GPU is an older version without independent thread scheduling, correct?

Comment: @Homer512 I'm not sure... I've started cuda since nvidia GPU supported independent thread scheduling. I haven't used old GPUs and thought about that.